# Angular: conditionally render based on whether value was received from Firebase DB

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I have a component:

```js
export class MainpageComponent implements OnInit {

  items: Observable<any[]>;
  displayElement = false; //whether we will display the elemet or display a loading thing

  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.items = db.list('questions').valueChanges();
  }
}
```

I am currently displaying the data I receive inside a swiper in the HTML template with no problems:

```html
<swiper>
<ng-template swiperSlide *ngFor="let item of items | async">
    <div>
        <h2> {{ item.prop1 }} </h2>
        <h5> {{ item.prop2}} </h5>
    </div>
</ng-template>
</swiper>
```

However, I now want to display the part above only after `items` have been loaded. And display something else (a loading indicator) while it loads. So I am planning something like this:

```html
<div *ngIf="displayElement; else elseBlock">Items are not here yet</div>
<ng-template #elseBlock>

<!---- old code ------>
<swiper>
<ng-template swiperSlide *ngFor="let item of items | async">
    <div>
        <h2> {{ item.prop1 }} </h2>
        <h5> {{ item.prop2}} </h5>
    </div>
</ng-template>
</swiper>   
<! --------------->

</ng-template>
```

My only problem is that I don't know how to update the `displayElement` variable value when `items` have been loaded from the firebase db (see first code block). I tried doing a `.then(()={})` but `valueChanges()` does not return a promise.

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`valueChanges()` is of type `Observable`, an `Observable` is a stream of events or data. To get the data from the database, you need to subscribe to the `Observable`. Therefore you have to use the `subscribe()` function:

```
db.list('questions').valueChanges().subscribe((res) =>{
    console.log(res);
    this.displayElement = true;
 },error => {
    console.log(error);
 },() => {
    console.log("completed");
});
```

The `subscribe` function takes 3 callbacks, the first one will be called whenever the Observable emits an item. Therefore you can change the value of `displayElement` after getting the first item from the database.

For reference:

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribe.html

Comment: I am coming to this a bit late. I thought it worked but I keep getting a problem in the `this.items` part of this line: `this.items = db.list(`questions`).etc`. When I add the `subscribe((res))` part, `this.items` is no longer receiving the expected values. I can't access `this.items` from inside the `subscribe((res))` to set if from there... It's a bit of a mess, but I would really appreciate if you could rewrite it while keeping the `this.items` in the begginning (- what would I need to do to make it receive the values?). Thank you.

Comment: Inside subscribe do `this.items = res` and when you declare items initialize it with empty array `item:any = []`